# Obter valor textview através de gridview/sql server

Tags: android, sql-server

Tenho uma gridview de uma coluna só constituída por quatro textviews e estou a carregar valores de uma base de dados SQL Server nela. Como faço para ao clicar numa linha da grid mostrar um outro campo (associado aos da linha) dessa tabela SQL numa textview à parte?
Ou seja conforme fosse clicando nas diversas linhas o valor da textview ia-se alterando.

Comment: seu banco e sql server e aplicação é android? o que você já fez?

Comment: Já carreguei linhas na gridview, excolhendo campos filtrados.